# Detecting a corrupted text file in java

Tags: data-corruption

Is there any way to detect the corrupted text file using java 1.6 onwards. We have tried using all the file readers and still it is not detecting the corruptness. Suppose if we change the `.exe` file to `.txt` file and still we are unable to detect the corruptness of the text file and reader is able to read the corrupted file.

Example of the code snippet we used:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader(destDir + fileName);
fr.read();
```

Comment: If you have tried something, you should present it.

Comment: What do you mean? An illegal file extension change does not make the file corrupted if it becomes a text file. And I don't mean just ".txt", but "text" as opposed to "binary"

Comment: Before we can answer, you would need to explain what you mean by "corrupted".